# Compare two columns which contain lists of words in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list

I am trying to look for the words that are not in common between two pandas columns that contain lists.

The words are not always in the same order and the length of the list can vary.

As an example

```
column1            column2
['a','b']          ['c','a','b']
['c','a']          ['a','b','d','c']
```

the result I want is

```
column3
['c']
['b','d']
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Both solutions give empty list on the first row when we swap the 2 elements of the 2 columns in the first row.

Comment: As there is no response from the 2 solution providers, I posted a new solution catering for the case `column1` is a superset of `column2` using `symmetric_difference()` instead of just `difference()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your target is to **look for words that are not in common between the 2 pandas columns**, I suppose you also want to find the uncommon elements when `column1` element list is a superset of `column2` list and vice versa.

Unfortunately, the 2 existing solutions doesn't handle for this case, e.g.

```
     column1       column2
0  [c, a, b]        [a, b]
1     [c, a]  [a, b, d, c]
```

Both the other solutions give result in `column3` as:

```
     column1       column2 column3
0  [c, a, b]        [a, b]      []             <==  empty list [] instead of ['c']
1     [c, a]  [a, b, d, c]  [b, d]
```

If you want the result above to show `['c']` instead of `[]` for the first row, you can do it this way:

Use the [`symmetric_difference()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.symmetric_difference) function instead:

```
df['column3'] = df.apply(lambda x: list(set(x['column1']).symmetric_difference(set(x['column2']))), axis=1)
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

     column1       column2 column3
0  [c, a, b]        [a, b]     [c]
1     [c, a]  [a, b, d, c]  [b, d]
```

Comment: You are right.. this actually works best in this case. I flagged this answer as correct. Thanks!

Comment: @Sarin  You are welcome!  It's always not that easy to craft good testing data to completely test a solution.  But remember to include a good mix of different cases (like in this case, some with column1 longer and some with column2 longer) in order to get a complete solution too!  :-)   Happy programming & have a nice day!  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this using `set` difference:

```
>>> df['column3'] = df.applymap(set).diff(axis=1).dropna(axis=1).squeeze().map(list)
>>> df
  column1       column2 column3
0  [a, b]     [c, a, b]     [c]
1  [c, a]  [a, b, d, c]  [b, d]
>>>
```

Comment: @SaraMichetti Your welcome, please accept if it helps by clicking the check mark :)

Comment: This doesn't work if element in `column1` is a superset of corresponding element of `column2` in the same row.   Try swap the 2 elements in the first row and check the result.

Answer (score 1):

We can reach the expected result by converting the `lists` in `sets`, then applying a `diff` and re-converting the result as `list` :

```py
>>> df.applymap(set).diff(axis=1).dropna(axis=1).applymap(list)
    column2
0   [c]
1   [b, d]
```